# Can you view and edit a PDF in Java using iText at the same time?

Tags: java, pdf, user-interface, interface, itext

I want to view the PDF in Java on a UI and, while viewing it, being able to add Items to it at the same time and, when these items are added, they update the PDF that I'm viewing to show the new information.

Is this possible using iText? Or any other way? If so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Its possible when you are using a VO class and passing the values and generated again..it ll be updated..and new datas added. Im not sure...Try and let me know wats happen...

Answer (score 0):

No , you cant view and edit a PDF in Java using iText at the same time.
When you will try to do it , it will give the following error.

```
The process cannot access the file 'myfile.pdf' because it is being used by another process.
```